# Como auditar registros guardando as alterações em JSON

Tags: postgresql, psql

Estou utilizando uma função para auditar registros nos eventos insert, update, delete para uma tabela do **PostGres 9.6**.

Peguei o script no [Git - audit-trigger](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql)

*O script foi implementado e está funcionando perfeitamente, porém um dos resultados que ele me traz no log de auditoria é:*

```
"id"=>"2", "ende"=>"Rua 2 de julho", "nome"=>"Amanda", "senha"=>"1234", "telefone"=>"069", "estaativo"=>"t", "ultimaalteracao"=>"2018-06-21 09:50:15.677835"
```

*Como fazer para que o resultado seja um JSON:*

```
{ 
    "id":2, 
    "ende":"Rua 2 de julho", 
    "nome":"Amanda", 
    "senha":"1234", 
    "telefone":"08799919991", 
    "estaativo":true, 
    "ultimaalteracao":"2018-06-21 09:50:15.677835"
}
```

*Já tentei alterar o script obtido acima usando a função `row_to_json`, segue a alteração:*

```
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
    --audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
    audit_row.row_data = hstore(row_to_json(OLD)) - excluded_cols;
   -- audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(NEW.*) - audit_row.row_data) - excluded_cols;
    audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(row_to_json(NEW)) - audit_row.row_data) - excluded_cols;
    IF audit_row.changed_fields = hstore('') THEN
        -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
    --audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
    audit_row.row_data = hstore(row_to_json(OLD)) - excluded_cols;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
    --audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols;
    audit_row.row_data = hstore(row_to_json(NEW)) - excluded_cols;
ELSIF (TG_LEVEL = 'STATEMENT' AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','TRUNCATE')) THEN
    audit_row.statement_only = 't';
ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION '[audit.if_modified_func] - Trigger func added as trigger for unhandled case: %, %',TG_OP, TG_LEVEL;
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;
INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*);
RETURN NULL;
```

*O erro obtido é:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este campo do log de auditoria certamente é do tipo `hstore`.

Você pode usar a função [`hstore_to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/hstore.html) para fazer a conversão de um campo do tipo `hstore` para `JSON`, veja só:

```
SELECT hstore_to_json('"id"=>"2", "ende"=>"Rua 2 de julho", "nome"=>"Amanda", "senha"=>"1234", "telefone"=>"069", "estaativo"=>"t", "ultimaalteracao"=>"2018-06-21 09:50:15.677835"')
```

Exemplo completo:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    ende TEXT,
    nome TEXT,
    senha TEXT,
    telefone TEXT,
    estaativo BOOLEAN,
    ultimaalteracao TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE tb_log
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    registro hstore
);

-- POPULANDO A TABELA tb_foobar
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, ende, nome, senha, telefone, estaativo, ultimaalteracao ) VALUES
( 1, 'Casa do Chapeu, 87', 'MARIA SILVA', '12345678', '(11) 9999-9090', true, NOW() ),
( 2, 'Rua sem Nome, 214', 'JOAO NINGUEM', '01010101', '(11) 9999-7744', false, NOW() ),
( 3, 'Fim do Mundo, 30', 'JESUS DE NAZARE', 'A1B2C3', '(11) 9999-3344', true, NOW() ),
( 4, 'Terra do Nunca, 21', 'MICHAEL JACKSON', '9876543', '(11) 9999-4567', false, NOW() ),
( 5, 'Rua da Ladainha, 10', 'FULANO DE TAL', '666777666', '(11) 9999-1234', true, NOW() );

-- POPULANDO A tb_log COM REGISTROS DO TIPO hstore
INSERT INTO tb_log ( id, registro ) (SELECT id, hstore(*) FROM tb_foobar);


-- CONVERTENDO REGISTROS PARA JSON
SELECT hstore_to_json(registro) FROM tb_log;
```

Comment: Só lembrando que o `hstore`, conforme link dado na resposta, é parte dos módulos adicionais (chamados também coletivamente de "contrib"), e para usá-lo é necessário instalar/compilar tais módulos (pacote `postgresql-contrib` no Ubuntu por ex.) e depois criar a extensão em seu banco com o comando `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`